# Create a neo4j graph from an hdfs file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j

I want to put the data that is in HDFS in a neo4j chart. Taking into account the suggestion given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51337661/create-neo4j-graph-with-spark), I used the neo4j-spark-connector, initializing them this way:

```
/usr/local/sparks/bin/spark-shell --conf spark.neo4j.url="bolt://192.xxx.xxx.xx:7687" --conf spark.neo4j.user="xxxx" --conf spark.neo4j.password="xxxx" --packages neo4j-contrib:neo4j-spark-connector:2.4.5-M1, graphframes:graphframes:0.2.0-spark2.0-s2.11
```

I read the file that is in the hdfs and put it in neo4j from the function Neo4jDataFrame.mergeEdgeList.

```
import org.neo4j.spark.dataframe.Neo4jDataFrame

object Neo4jTeste {

  def main {
  
    val lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://.../testeNodes.csv")
    
    val filteredlines = lines.map(_.split("-")).map{x => (x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3))}
    val newNames = Seq("name","apelido","city","date")
    val df = filteredlines.toDF(newNames: _*)

    Neo4jDataFrame.mergeEdgeList(sc, df, ("Name", Seq("name")),("HAPPENED_IN", Seq.empty), ("Age", Seq("age")))
   }    }
```

However, as my data is very large, neo4j is unable to represent all nodes. I think the problem is with the function.

I've tried it this way too:

```
import org.neo4j.spark._

val neo = Neo4j(sc)

val rdd = neo.cypher("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN id(n) as id ").loadRowRdd
```

However, this way I cannot read the HDFS file or divide it into columns

Can someone help me find another solution? With the Neo4jDataFrame.mergeEdgeList function, I only see 150 nodes instead of the 500 expected.

Comment: MariaC, can you tell me exact problem .. if you gave some code in eidtor when I execute that code ... it showing some errors.. i am not sure those issues are from code or editor..  please remove those editor & post your input and expected output, if possible ??

Comment: @Srinivas The code with the Neo4jDataFrame.mergeEdgeList function works.
But there should be appear 500 nodes, and pops up only 150, I don't know why

Comment: Because you use MERGE, is it possible that the same nodes in your dataset appear more than once

Comment: @TomažBratanič But then is there another solution? It is that for more lines that the file has, my neo4j chart only appears 158 nodes

Comment: Can you try to create edge lists instead of merge? I don't have experience with this tool unfortunately